# Trouble setting Sublime Text as default editor for entering Git commit message

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, git, sublimetext

I am learning `git` command-line. I wish to set Sublime Text as the default editor for entering commit message, when I run the `git commit` command from Terminal.

But when trying to do so, I am running into the following error:

> error: There was a problem with the editor ''/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

What could be going wrong? How do I resolve the error message, and set things such that Sublime Text opens automatically for entering commit message when running `git commit` command from Terminal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you share how are you trying to configure Sublime Text as the default editor for entering git commit message? If you are following a tutorial, please share the link. If you ran a command to configure the editor with git, please share the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

Start by making sure you have [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) for macOS installed on your computer. You can install it using either of the following:

1. Download it from the official website from the [download page](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).
2. If you use Homebrew, you can install it via Homebrew Cask by running the following command-line in Terminal.app in macOS:

   `brew cask install sublime-text`

Once you have the app installed, it should be available under `/Applications` directory on your Mac. (Assuming that in case 1, you have copied the **Sublime Text.app** bundle into the `/Applications` folder as instructed).

Once installed, this should be the path of the **Sublime Text.app** bundle and the editors executable file respectively:

1. **App bundle**: `/Applications/Sublime Text.app`
2. **Executable**: `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text`

Now, we'll use the executable's path above to set it as the editor for `git` command to use for writing commit message. Run the following command to do so:

```
git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text"
```

Notice how we have:

1. Specified the path for the executable and not the app bundle.
2. Included the path into double-quotes
3. Backslash-escaped the space characters present in the path.

Once done you'd be set. Now make sure that the editor is not running, go to the Terminal, change to the directory containing your repository, stage some changes, and run the commit command. Sublime Text should be opened for you to enter the commit message. Write your commit message, save the file (you can use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), and quit the editor. Your commit should get recorded.

Now that was about how to configure and use the desired editor. Whether it's a recommended approach or not is a matter of personal preference. Most folks prefer using a command-line editor which makes the overall workflow much simpler as everything gets done then and there without leaving the Terminal.

You may want to refer to this excellent post to learn in detail:

- [Using TextEdit as your git editor](https://ericasadun.com/2018/07/12/using-textedit-as-your-git-editor/)

If you have installed Sublime Text in an alternate location (such as in `~/Applications`, i.e. a folder in your Home directory), you'd have to change to use the appropriate path.